# Est-ce que « laisse tomber » est impoli ou agressif ?

Tags: vocabulaire, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique

Je me plante toujours quand je veux dire “never mind” en français.

Par exemple, l’autre jour, j’étais à la caisse chez Monoprix et je voulais chercher quelque chose que je m'étais rendu compte avoir oublié juste avant d’y arriver pour payer. Mais il y avait beaucoup de monde derrière moi donc j'hésitais.

La caissière m’a demandé si j’avais besoin de quelque chose. Je voulais dire “no, never mind” et donc j’ai dit « non, laisse tomber c’est bon » mais quand j’y réfléchis, peut-être que c’est un peu impoli ?

Est-ce que ça pourrait se traduire par “no leave it alone!” ? parce que dans ce cas, en anglais, ça serait plutôt intense, voire vulgaire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quand on s'adresse à des inconnus ou au personnel d'un magasin, le tutoiement n'est pas l'usage en France.

Si tu connais très bien la caissière et que vous vous tutoyiez déjà auparavant, il n'y a pas de problème à dire *laisse tomber* bien que ce ne soit pas exactement la bonne formule car la caissière n'a rien à "laisser tomber" (la phrase pourrait faire sous entendre que la caissière est trop insistante), elle a juste posé une question et c'est à toi de laisser tomber ou pas.

*Laissez tomber* (vouvoiement) est aussi un peu trop familier et directif dans ce contexte. Je dirais plutôt quelque chose comme:

> Non, pas de problème, merci.

Comment: Merci @jilliagre - c'est très clair.

Answer (score 4):

Oui, c'est un peu malpoli de parler comme ça à une caissière, c'est plus le langage que l'on emploierai pour parler à un copain. D'abord, je ne tutoierais pas une caissière de supermarché que je ne connais pas. Ensuite l'expression "laisse tomber" employée à l'impératif est souvent interprétée comme dédaigneuse, pour couper court à une conversation que l'on ne souhaite pas poursuivre plus loin. Je pense en effet que "No, leave it alone." est une traduction assez proche.

Vous auriez pu dire quelque chose comme: "Non non, tout va bien, merci !"

Comment: https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/a/158/1109

Comment: Merci @Jonathan, c'est exactement ce que je pensais.

Answer (score 1):

Il n'y a rien d'impoli ni d'agressif dans l'expression « *laisser tomber* ». Le problème est qu'elle ne convient pas au contexte décrit. On demande à quelqu'un de *laisser tomber quelque chose* lorsque cette personne est engagée dans un processus plus ou moins long et  plus ou moins compliqué qui a été initié soit par la personne elle-même soit par  le biais de notre initiative ou encore sur l'initiative de la personne et de nous-même, et on dit cela lorsque l'on ne voit aucun intérêt dans la poursuite de ce processus, soit aucun intérêt pour la personne elle-même, soit aucun pour nous, soit encore pour les deux; c'est tout simplement une demande d'arrêter le processus.
Ce que l'on peut dire c'est que c'est une expression assez familière qui a un sens plus ou moins péjoratif: elle exprime souvent que la personne qui parle  se fait une idée méprisable du processus ou le considère comme trivial plutôt que  simplement inutile. De plus, lorsque l'on dit de quelqu'un qu'*il/elle a laissé tombé quelque chose* on introduit parfois la connotation que cette personne est défaillante dans un des aspects de son caractère: manque d'intérêt, peu de force d'âme, manque de sérieux, pas de suite dans les idées, etc. ; on n'introduit pas ces connotations lorsque l'on utilise à la place de « laisser tomber » le synonyme « *abandonner* », lorsque celui-ci convient. Donc en utilisant cette expression, même lorsqu'elle est assez justifiée comme dans le cas par exemple d'une caissière qui essaie de replacer correctement le bouchon de votre bocal de café instantané qui semble avoir un défaut et se détache, on n'est pas libéré entièrement de ces connotations et dans le cas de cet exemple il vaut mieux dire quelque chose comme « (Non,) ne vous donnez pas la peine » ou « Laissez, je m'arrangerais » ou « Laissez, je vais aller chercher un autre bocal. ». Disons que si ce n'est pas plus poli, ça dénote d'un langage plus raffiné. On peut donc dire « laissez tomber » sans commettre une faute fondamentale de langage, mais bien sûr, dans ce cas de caissière qui pose une simple question (Avez-vous besoin de quelque chose ?), ce qui ne représente pas un processus en cours d'exécution, cela ne convient pas, mais ça ne convient pas seulement de par le contexte qui ne correspond pas. Aurait été approprié quelque chose comme « Je n'ai besoin de rien, merci ! » ou « Non, merci ! » ou encore « Je pensais revenir dans les rayons pour chercher un article mais j'ai changé d'avis, je ferai sans, merci ! ».

Ce qui aura pu être malpoli c'est seulement le tutoiement dans le cas où la caissière n'aurait pas été l'une de vos connaissances intimes, une de celles que vous avez l'habitude de tutoyer.

Comment: Pourquoi est-ce que cette réponse était votée en bas? Il me semble utile, et donc s'il y a quelque chose qui n'est pas correct, je voudrais savoir.

Comment: @DerekAllums Je suis celui qui l'a écrite et je devrais donc avoir une idée de ses faiblesses, mais je ne vois pas moi-même une raison suffisante pour le vote négatif. Il est possible que la raison soit que je caractérise cette expression comme plutôt familière, mais pourtant dans un style soutenu et sans connotations péjoratives on lui préfère certainement le verbe « abandonner ».

Answer (score 1):

Le problème avec l'expression "laisse tomber" dans ce contexte n'est pas seulement le niveau de familiarité, mais aussi et surtout le sens qui n'est pas le bon : Ton "laisse tomber" laisse penser que c'est la caissière qui insiste ou s'obstine à faire quelque chose.

Pour ne citer que deux exemples, "Laisse tomber" est le genre d'expression que l'on dit :

- à un ami qui s'obstine dans une discussion houleuse et sans fin
- à un ami qui cherche à tout prix à reconquérir son ex-copine, alors que ça semble compromis.

Dans ton cas, ce n'est pas la caissière qui abandonne, c'est toi qui "laisse tomber" ce que tu voulais faire au départ.

Tu aurais donc pû dire "Non, je laisse tomber", mais le plus naturel de mon point de vue aurait été quelque chose comme :

> "Non, j'avais oublié quelque chose, mais tant pis!"

ou

> "Merci, rien de grave, ça va aller"

Answer (score 1):

Il est vrai que l'expression "Laisse Tomber" peut froisser selon la sensibilité, surtout lorsque l'on s'adresse à des inconnus...

Il est peut-être mieux d'utiliser une expression telle que :

" Si cela ne vous dérange pas, pourrions-nous passer sur cette question ?"

Attention quand même au ton de la voix qui a le pouvoir de complètement changer le sens de cette phrase pourtant polie à la base.